# SQL Server 2000 trouble converting nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2000

Within a table there is a column with datatype datetime and I need to compare the data within this column with the current date and time.

I am attempting a convert on the field but I receive

```
Syntax error converting datetime from character string
```

The values in the column unfortunately have three different formats (legacy junk)

```
November 28, 2005 -or-
5/1/2011 12:00:00 AM -or-
null
```

My code I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT 1 from webprograms where convert(datetime, ApplicationDueDate) < getdate()
```

Can someone help diagnose the problem please

Comment: Does the data say `'null'` as a string or is the record actually `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both those date formats convert just fine. The default `convert` algorithm does a pretty decent job of being flexible about what it's given. And a `null` string, as I commented earlier`, will always convert to a`null`datetime value: per the standard, any expression that involving`null`yields`null`.

I suspect you've got a data problem. Most likely junk characters like embedded CR, LF or CR+LF (line breaks). HT (tab) characters also seems to break `convert()`. You (or your DBAs) probably need to do a data cleanup to get rid of the junk characters. Or you need to work around the problem and write an ugly expression to fix the bad data at runtime.

A query like this should identify the problem data:

```
select myCruftyDateTimeColumn,count(*)
from foo
where myCruftyDateTimeColumn is not null
  -- m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM format
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like '[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M'
  -- month d, yyyy alternatives, 2 digit days
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'January [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'February [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'March [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and ...
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'October [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'November [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'December [0-9][0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  -- month d, yyyy alternatives, 2 digit days
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'January [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'February [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'March [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and ...
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'October [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'November [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  and myCruftyDateTimeColumn not like 'December [0-9], [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
group by myCruftyDateTimeColumn
order by 1
```

You might want to load a temp table with the results and then, from that

```
select *,convert(varbinary,myCruftyDateTimeColumn)
from #bad_data
```

to identify exactly what the bogus characters are.

Comment: LOL Thats the problem I am the "DBA" now. The old person that used to run this operation didn't have a clue what he was doing (redundancies and empty columns everywhere) I am learning as I go along

Comment: ok I am actually getting back 27 rows of data with that query. The items being returned all look good though. They are either valid dates or valid dates and times

Comment: I also dumped teh results into a temp table and the third column is giving me something like "0x4400650063002E002000310035002C0020003200300030003800"

Comment: AHHA!!! there are 6 dates that are either abbreviated, spelled wrong and in one instance there is not a space between the comma and year

Comment: It won't care about the space between the comma and the year. It won't mind 3-character month abbreviations, either (`"Jan 12,2009"` will work just fine, thank-you-very-much, but not so much with something like  `"Janu 12, 2009"`). And mis-spelled month names are right out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert to a newer version of SQL Server? If so, the problem will cure itself. If not, you have to exclude the nulls from the equation, as they are the issue here.

I don't think it matters if your top 1 is selecting a null or not as I think the evaluation fails as the column is nullable. I did a quick test in SQL Server 2008 R2 and it works fine.

Comment: We are converting but not for awhile. and this needs to be done before that as the date we are converting over is unknown. I have also tried with a added clause of NOT ApplicationDueDate IS NULL but still getting the error

Comment: Oh and I put the 1 in there just to make the query simple, it has nothing to do with what I am actually returning

Comment: @matt - based on his answer it only matters if the column accepts `NULL`, not if any of the data actually is.

Comment: yes the column does except nulls, I have tried to exclude the nulls using NOT ApplicationDueDate IS NULL (and the other syntax) and tried converting to a fake date (ie. ISNULL(ApplicationDueDate, '01/01/1900')) but that didnt work either

Comment: A `null` string will convert to a datetime. It will be a `null` datetime, though. A nil string ('') will convert to `1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000`

Comment: I tried it in my SQL Server 2008 R2 test server and getting a conversion error as well, I am thinking that there is an issue with the data within that column itself. The error is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: However: the ApplicationDueDate field within my test only has the format of "November 28, 2005" or it is NULL

Comment: If you are getting an issue with newer versions of SQL Server, it is not the null, but some data that cannot convert to a datetime. That is a bit harder to conquer. You can easily CASE WHEN the NULL, but conversion from "My name is jack" to Date cannot easily be tested in the WHERE clause.